# Algorithms for finding unique solutions of NP-complete problems

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, search-problem, unique-solution

The complexity of algorithms that *find* unique solution for an NP-complete problem (the input is guaranteed to have a unique solution) seems to shed light on the hardness character of different NP search problems. Two well known examples are the unique k-SAT search problem and solving Sudoku puzzle. As far as I know, the best algorithms for both are still exponential. I am interested in **large** gaps (if any exists) between the complexity of search algorithms for different NP-complete problems.

What complexity class does represent such search problems? Is there a survey paper of algorithms for such search problems?

This is motivated by two posts, [NP-Complete problems that admit an efficient algorithm under the promise of a unique solution](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/37550), and [Examples where the uniqueness of the solution makes it easier to find](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22093).

Comment: https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:U#us